# mod_wsgi won't compile - cannot find -lpython3.2

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install Python 3.2 and mod_wsgi on my web server, but I am not having much luck.

I downloaded the Python source files and compiled using this command:

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/opt/python-3-2 LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /opt/python-3-2/lib"
```

I also modified my path variable to include `/opt/python-3-2/bin` and created a symlink to the `python3` binary from `/opt/python-3-2/bin/python`. Now if I run `python` from the command line I get the proper prompt.

```
> python
Python 3.2.2 (default, Jan 20 2012, 18:14:20)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I am using the following settings to compile the latest version of mod_wsgi

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-python=/opt/python-3-2/bin/python3
```

This produces the following errors

```
mod_wsgi.c:8937: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8939: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8941: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8945: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8965: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8967: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8970: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_daemon_worker':
mod_wsgi.c:10279: warning: unused variable 'duration'
mod_wsgi.c:10278: warning: unused variable 'start'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_hook_daemon_handler':
mod_wsgi.c:12499: warning: unused variable 'i'
mod_wsgi.c:12497: warning: unused variable 'elts'
mod_wsgi.c:12496: warning: unused variable 'head'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Auth_environ':
mod_wsgi.c:13375: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
mod_wsgi.c: At top level:
mod_wsgi.c:7154: warning: 'wsgi_set_py3k_warning_flag' defined but not used
mod_wsgi.c:7856: warning: 'wsgi_set_user_authoritative' defined but not used
mod_wsgi.c:14414: warning: 'wsgi_hook_check_user_id' defined but not used
/usr/lib/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/lib/httpd/modules -module -avoid-version    mod_wsgi.lo -L/opt/python-3-2/lib -L/opt/python-3-2/lib/python3.2/config -lpython3.2 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

I have tried creating a symlink from `/opt/python-3-2/lib/python3.2/config -> /opt/python-3-2/lib/libpython3.so` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must currently use mod_wsgi source code from source code repository for Python 3.2, you cannot use mod_wsgi 3.3 source code.

Comment: Exact same issue with mod_wsgi 3.2

Comment: I didn't say to use mod_wsgi 3.2. I said that if using Python 3.2, but need to use the mod_wsgi source code from the source code repository. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/source/checkout